# java array list

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

its been awhile since i used java the last time and am trying to brush up on couple of things.

```
import java.util.*;

public class bitStrings {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        Scanner inputBitString = new Scanner(System.in);        

        //input.
        String binArray;

        ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(inputBitString.hasNext()){

            binArray=inputBitString.next();         
            myArr.add(binArray);
            System.out.println(myArr);      

            for(int i=0;i<myArr.size();i++){
                if(myArr(i)=="1") myArr(i)=="10";
                else myArr(i)=="01"
            }
        }

    }

}
```

So I want to store the input in an array from the user's keyboard input. so if the user types "1010", the for loop will go through the array and replaces the "1" with "10" and "0" with "01".
so the resulting output will be "10011001"

Thanks

Comment: What is the question here? i.e. which bit of the code is not working - the getting user input or the changing it to the encoded values?

Comment: I agree with James, the question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry. The code won't compile at the for loop.

Comment: When you are doing `import java.util.*` you do not need to do `java.util.Scanner`.

Comment: *"The code won't compile at the for loop."*  What is the compiler reporting?  It is always better to copy/paste the output, to prevent people having to play '20 questions' - which is not a popular game around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> myArrDub = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String str = bf.readLine();

for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    String tempStr = new String();
    tempStr += str.charAt(i);
    myArr.add(tempStr);
}

System.out.println(myArr);

for(int i=0;i<myArr.size();i++){
    if(myArr.get(i).equals("1"))
    myArrDub.add("10");
else
    myArrDub.add("01");
}
```

Comment: you should use `.equals` not `==` to compare strings

Answer (score 2):

To compare `String` contents you should use `equals`:

```
myArr.get(i).equals( "1" );
```

Otherwise, you are comparing object references.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that your code won't compile or work properly.  I'd write it like this:

```
if("1".equals(myArr.get(i))) {
    myArr.set(i, "10");
} else {
    myArr.set(i, "01");
}
```

Pay attention to style - it matters, even with trivial examples like this one.

Didn't notice the use of `List` at first.

Comment: its still giving me an error.

Comment: You've got a lot of brushing up to to.

Comment: This will error, it does not access the List (you should be using the get(i) method)

Comment: Fixed that, too.  An IDE like IntelliJ would have pointed all this out right away.  I didn't think it was worth the effort to fire up IntelliJ to sort this out.  Apparently I should have.

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot (or shouldn't) modify a list while you're iterating over it. If it were me, I would store the encoded values in a new (possibly temporary) ArrayList and then reasign the old one once finished.

As has been stated you should use .equals not == to compare strings. Also, the syntax for reading a value from a List is `myArr.get(i)`; not `myArr(i)` as you have used.

Additionally, when you use Scanner#next() it will return a String, so if a user entered "1010" the entire sequence would be stored in a single element, each character would not get its own index.

Finally, Class names, by convention, should begin with a capital letter.

Here is how I would do it (using Console, not scanner). I believe this is the effect you're after:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class BitStrings{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Console c = System.console();
        List<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(null == c){ 
            //exit gracefully
        }

        String entry = c.readLine("Enter the bits: "); // Wait for user entry

        for(int i = 0; i < entry.length(); i++){
            String bit = entry.substring(i, i+1);
            if("1".equals(bit)) myArr.add("10");
            else myArr.add("01");
        }
        //If we want to print it out
        for(String element : myArr) System.out.print(s);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most efficient way, but it works:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String user = "1010";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for ( char c : user.toCharArray() ) {
            if ( c == '1' )
                sb.append( "10" );
            else
                sb.append( "01" );
        }
        System.out.println( sb );
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't reading user input from standard in

Comment: My aim was to solve what he asked about, which was replacing sub-strings.

Comment: fair enough, just making sure you didn't miss that part :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct:

```
    ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str = bf.readLine();
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        myArr.add("" + str.charAt(i));

    for(int i=0;i<myArr.size();i++){
        if(myArr.get(i).equals("1"))
            myArr.set(i, "10");
        else
            myArr.set(i, "01");
    }
```